# Conditionally set anonymize_ip in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I am trying to implement tracking acceptance on a Gatsby site using `gatsby-plugin-google-gtag` and a custom cookie prompt component.

Currnetly the tracking code is setup and working and the cookie prompt component is conditionally rendering depending if the user has previously made their choice regarding tracking. Where things are failing is trying to conditionally set `anonymize_ip` based on the users choice. I have tried to set `true/false` based on a ternary statement in `gatsby-config.js`, but this seems to error login issues in terminal relating to GraphQL (not linked).

`anonymize_ip: document.cookie.match(/^(.*;)?\s*ga-disabled\s*=\s*[^;]+(.*)?$/) ? true : false, // If cookie exists, set value to true`

Does anyone know the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

**Cookie Prompt**

```
import React from "react";
import { setCookie } from "../../assets/js/utils/cookies";

const CookiesPrompt = () =>  {
    
    const gaOptout = () => {
        setCookie('ga-disabled', true, 30);
    }

    const gaAccept = () => {
        setCookie('ga-hide-prompt', true, 30);
    }

    return (
        <div className="cookies-prompt">
            <div className="cookies-prompt__wrap">
                <div className="cookies-prompt__title">This website uses cookies</div>
                <button onClick={() => gaOptout()} className="cookies-prompt__link button--non">I wish to opt-out</button>
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => gaAccept()} className="cookies-prompt__button button button--primary">Accept</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CookiesPrompt;
```

**Gatsby-config.js**

```
plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-sass", "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet", "gatsby-transformer-json", "gatsby-plugin-image", "gatsby-plugin-sharp", "gatsby-transformer-sharp", 
    {
        resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`,
        options: {
        // You can add multiple tracking ids and a pageview event will be fired for all of them.
        trackingIds: [
            'G-xxxxxxx', // Google Analytics / GA
        ],
        // This object gets passed directly to the gtag config command
        // This config will be shared across all trackingIds
        gtagConfig: {
            // optimize_id: 'OPT_CONTAINER_ID',
            anonymize_ip: document.cookie.match(/^(.*;)?\s*ga-disabled\s*=\s*[^;]+(.*)?$/) ? true : false, // If cookie exists, set value to true
            cookie_expires: 0,
        },
        // This object is used for configuration specific to this plugin
        pluginConfig: {
            // Puts tracking script in the head instead of the body
            head: false,
            // Setting this parameter is also optional
            respectDNT: true,
            // Avoids sending pageview hits from custom paths
            exclude: ['/preview/**', '/do-not-track/me/too/'],
        },
        },
    },
    {
        resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
        options: {
            name: 'data',  // Identifier. Will then be queried as `dataJson`
            path: './src/assets/data',   // Source folder containing the JSON files
        },
    },
    {
        resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
        options: {
            name: 'projectImages',  // Identifier. Will then be queried as `projectImagesJson' ?
            path: './public/static/projects',   // Source folder containing the JSON files
        },
    },
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

`gatsby-config.js` configurations are set on build-time, not on runtime, so there's no way that you can listen `document` in that environment/file on-demand.

However, you can use the anonymize IP based on user choice (`onClick`) by triggering the `gaOptout()` function:

```
<div onClick={gaOptout}>Deactivate Google Tracking</a>
```

Where `gaOptout`:

```
function gaOptout() {
  ;(document.cookie =
    disableStr + "=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC;path=/"),
    (window[disableStr] = !0)
}

var gaProperty = "UA-XXXXXXXX-X",
  disableStr = "ga-disable-" + gaProperty
document.cookie.indexOf(disableStr + "=true") > -1 && (window[disableStr] = !0)
```